# Unable to get notification from Fabric when a tester adds new UUID

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I am new to Fabric, and I am tying to get the UUID added by the tester, but I am not getting any notifications regarding new UUID added. And I am not able to see the new UUID in Fabric when I try to give a release or new build to the tester (internal testing team). 
Can anyone help me to resolve this problem. Any steps and any other methods to resolve the same is much appreciated.

Comment: How you are using to deploy your app for Internal tester ?

Comment: I am using Fabric to deploy the build. we have defined set of testers. I have integrated Fabric with XCode and once I create archive it will navigate to Fabric for distribution link. And I select the email of the tesres/groups, will add release notes and distribute.